# Microsoft Computer Vision OCR : Disable grouping text by regions

Tags: c#, service, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I've been using Microsoft Computer Vision to read receipts, trying to find an alternative to Abby's OCR as there is a substantial price difference.

The results I get are always grouped by regions. This obviously makes it much harder to identify the corresponding fields with their amounts.

Is there a way through Microsoft Vision or anyway at all that I can achieve the same aligned output as Abby's?

Here's an image with both results and the receipt

Ocr Results

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is not a complete solution but I think it's enough to get you started.

The Computer Vision API returns a [JSON result](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/587f2cf1154055056008f201) with a `lines` property that is just an array of objects with a `boundingBox` property.

These `boundingBox`es are the X,Y coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the "square" of each phrase.

You basically need to process this array and "sort" the items based on this property.

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqkn2mo0/) you'll see that I'm sorting the lines by Y coordinate and then grouping them.

What's left to do is be "smarter" about the grouping - if the Y coordinates are 201 and 202 you can assume that they are on the same line and just add them to one same line, sorted by ascending X coordinate.

**Code:**

```
if (jsonResponse.status == 'Succeeded') {

  var result = '';
  // Sort lines by Y coordinate
  jsonResponse.recognitionResult.lines.sort(function(a, b) {
    var topLeftYCoordA = a.boundingBox[1];
    var topLeftYCoordB = b.boundingBox[1];
    if (topLeftYCoordA > topLeftYCoordB) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (topLeftYCoordA < topLeftYCoordB) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  })

  // group lines by Y coordinate
  var grouped = {};

  jsonResponse.recognitionResult.lines.map(function(line) {
    var topLeftYcoordinate = line.boundingBox[1];
    if (!grouped[topLeftYcoordinate]) {
      grouped[topLeftYcoordinate] = line;
    } else {
      grouped[topLeftYcoordinate] += line;
    }
  });
  Object.keys(grouped).forEach(function(yCoordinate) {
    result += yCoordinate + ' - ' + grouped[yCoordinate].text + '</br>';
  })
  $(".right").html(result);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]